# no HDMI driver for H61M/U3S3? Can't connect to TV

Tags: drivers, hdmi

My computer has an HDMI out port, but it doesn't seem to work. Motherboard is H61M/U3S3. The monitor I use is hooked into an added video card, but I would also like it to be hooked up to my TV via HDMI. There doesn't seem to be any drivers for the HDMI on this motherboard. I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: if the motherboard has the hdmi port but you are overriding and using the added video card, it is unlikely it will work. If the video card had the hdmi you might have a way to get it to work. use either the video card on the mobo or a video card that has one

Comment: This seems to be the case. I uninstalled the video card and now the motherboard HDMI and DVI work. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a video card overrides the onboard hdmi of the motherboard. Get a video card with hdmi, or disable the addon card so the integrated video hdmi is what is used by the system instead.